# PHP/MySQL: bind_param malfunction when using mysql function inside prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, bindparam

I'm having trouble encrypting a password when adding an entry into mysql using php bound parameters. Everything works just fine with 2 bound parameters ($username and $password) being inserted directly into the username and password field. But, when I try to add a third $salt variable and insert password with the sha2 function, it won't execute correctly anymore. The code below will print to my debug console "couldn't execute" each time. Why?

```
$stmt = $GLOBALS['mysqli']->stmt_init();
$sql = "INSERT INTO users ( username, password ) VALUES ( ?, sha2(concat(?,?),256) ) ";
if($stmt->prepare($sql)){
    $stmt->bind_param('sss',$username,$password,$salt);
    if($stmt->execute()){
        if($stmt->affected_rows>0){ $userID=$stmt->insert_id; }
    }
    else{ wdebug("couldn't execute"); }
    $stmt->close();     
}
```

Comment: Can you get the *actual* error from the database instead of "couldn't execute"?

Comment: Use `$stmt->error` to get the error message.

Comment: new to mysql, give me a minute...

Comment: found the problem...the error message was "Data too long for column 'password' at row1" and indeed my password column was only varchar(32). Setting it to varchar(64) did the trick. Thanks guys